# Find And Replace with Multiple Words

Tags: replace, ms-word, find

I am trying to replace the same word in multiple files with different words.

for instance, document 1 should search for word x, and replace it with word 1 from the list. 
Document 2 replaces word x with word 2 from the list
document 3 replaces word x from word 3 from the list etc. etc.

I have tried textcrawler, and some macros - but I don't know if this is possible or the best way to start.

Comment: Please show us the code of what you have tried so far. We will not write a complete solution for you!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make it Clear first. Give examples of words and name of documents. It is certainly possible. Show us the code you got so far.